# How to download latest jruby

Tags: rvm, jruby

The following command downloads 1.7.2, but I need to pull the latest version. How should I do that?

```
rvm install jruby
http://jruby.org.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/1.7.2/jruby-bin-1.7.2.tar.gz - #configure
jruby-1.7.2 - #download
```

Comment: use latest jruby version number in your command above?

Comment: Use the backspace button to remove the characters "1.7.2" and type in "2.0.0" instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update RVM:

```
rvm get head
rvm install jruby
```